# model passed College.WebInterface.Models.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel but instance requires a mdel itm of typ College.WebInterface.Models.Department

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, mvvm, viewmodel

Controller code

```
///Controller
public IActionResult Index() { 
    HomeIndexViewModel HomePageModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();
    //List<Notification> nf = new List<Notification>();
    var f = (from n in _context.Notifications.OrderByDescending(n => n.Date)  select n).Take(5);
    HomePageModel.Notifications.AddRange(f);        
      return View(HomePageModel);
    }
```

Razor Page code

```
    ///Razor-View Code 
    @model College.WebInterface.Models.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel
    <h1>Welcome </h1>
```

I am getting this error even after using the correct objects and models. what might be the reason. TIA

Comment: Do you use `College.WebInterface.Models.Department` somewhere in your view?Such as the property of `College.WebInterface.Models.Department`.

Comment: No .. there is only single tag in view..  <h1>Welcome </h1>.. I removed all code from the page... still its showing same error

Comment: Are you sure the action is returning the view with `@model College.WebInterface.Models.ViewModels.HomeIndexViewModel`?

Comment: you can check the code urself..  
'**HomeIndexViewModel HomePageModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();**'

Comment: if u need i can share the github link... its basic project not much there ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue in another forum .. there was a reference to College.WebInterface.Models.Department in the main Layout page... after removing that reference it worked perfectly...

Comment: Made it as resolved your own question or  put it into first post.